# Probability of 2 real number being between 1/2 and (-1/2)

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Got this question on a multiple choice test and had no idea how to solve it.

Q: Let $X,Y,$ and $Z$ be independent random variables uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$. What is 
$$
\mathbb P\left(|X-Y| < \frac12, |Y-Z|\lt \frac12\right)\quad ?
$$
A: $\frac34$

B: $\frac{7}{12}$

C: $\frac 14$

D: $\frac 12$

E: $\frac 23$

Comment: Do not repost: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3562616/321264.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your region.  You should be able to calculate the volume from this:

[image]

Comment: That is way outside the scope of my grade 11 mathematical ability. I think I'll let this question rest. ;)